# Get ISP provider name in winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to get the ISP provider name and display it whenever I run my winform application. Can anybody suggest me any way to do that.

I know that I can achieve this by using webclient class, I am also getting the result but I do not want to send a request to another website and find out the ISP name, for the simple reason that, "what if that service websites stops providing free service ?". I want another way around for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you assume internet connectivity or do you have to check? Is the machine IPv4 or IPv6? Do you have access to your world-visible IP address?

Comment: @Shai - I know that I can achieve this by using webclient class, I am also getting the result but I do not want to send a request to anothere website and find out the ISP name. I want another way around for this.

Comment: @user952838 I don't think that's possible. there is no way for your client to guess what's your ISP. a good idea would be to check the Top-Level Domain of the client's host.

Comment: @StaWho - Yes it has internet connectivity, and it can either IPV4 or IPV6, yes I have an IP address.

Comment: @user952838 - Are you connected to a network device ( i.e. router ) if you are then you do not likely have an ip address. There is no wa to know who owns an ip address without looking at a database, and unless you have that database stored on the computer itself, then your only choice is an external service.  Does your ip address look like 192.x.x.x by chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use external services to determine this you will need local copy of IP-to-ISP database (I'll let you google this one, but there's definitely one out there that's free and has v4 and v6 mappings). If you have external IP it's simple from there.

Comment: My opinion is that he should just use a free web service, unless he wants to pay 200$ for a commercial database for example http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db2-ip-country-isp (I couldn't find any free db, but who knows maybe there are some). Besides, database would have to be updated which makes things complicated also.

Comment: Personally I would use external service too, especially that the app has internet connectivity available and I'd need much less code to achieve required functionality, but the requirement is different ;) As for the DB, I use free IP to country in one of my side projects and remember there was ip-to-country-isp DB available for download too, just for the world can't remember where I got it from.

Comment: I will give you a +1 if you can find a free database :)

Comment: @StaWho - As there is no other alternative to this apart from what you have suggested, which external website will you advice me to use if I go with using the webclient class.

Comment: @user952838 - sorry but can't advise you on this one. I never used any of those services so can't really tell the quality

Comment: @user952838 - You should mark this as the answer to your question.